# How to enable WakaTime for the Mathematica front end?

Tags: external-calls, editing, api

[WakaTime](https://wakatime.com) is a tool for logging one's coding activities, and now have amazing coverage for code editors. Although I write Wolfram in VS Code, I still spend a lot of time tweaking and testing in the notebook interface. Is there a way to link the WakaTime API to Mathematica?

Comment: I have an attempt in the early stage, and I put it in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Gravifer/48dad1b2192741ac718f739eb1a25a30). It is far from desirable, But I hope this brings wisdom from the community.

Answer (score 1):

I have expanded the initial thoughts into a draft package.

```
(* ::Package:: *)

(* ::Title:: *)
(*Mathematica WakaTime Plugin*)


(* ::Author:: *)
(*Author: Gravifer*)
(*Date: 2021-02-21*)
(*Version: 0.0.3*)


BeginPackage["WakaTime`"]
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]


Begin["`Private`"]
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]


GetWakaEXE[]:=If[#[["ExitCode"]]==0,Identity[$wakaEXE=StringReplace[#[["StandardOutput"]],{"\\"->"/","\r"->"","\n"->""}]],Print["wakatime.exe is not found"];$Failed]&@RunProcess[{"where.exe", "wakatime"}]
GetWakaEXE[]
$WakaTimePluginVersion="v0.0.3"
WakaTime::unsaved="The current file is not on the disk, and the heartbeat cannot be sent. (This message only issue once for the current file)";
Once[If[ValueQ[$PrePrint],$WakaTimePreReadBackUp=$PreRead]]


UpdateHeartbeat[]:=(Once[$LastHeartbeat=AbsoluteTime[]];
  If[Not[ValueQ[$LastHeartbeat]]&&(AbsoluteTime[]-$LastHeartbeat>0),
  Quiet@Unset@Once[$LastHeartbeat=AbsoluteTime[]];Once[$LastHeartbeat=AbsoluteTime[]];True,
  False])


GetGitFolder[]:=(If[#[["ExitCode"]]==0,
  Set[$gitFolder,Last[FileNameSplit@#[["StandardOutput"]]]],
  Unset[$gitFolder]]&@Evaluate[RunProcess[{"git","rev-parse","--show-toplevel"}]];)


GetCurrentProject[]:=($CurrentProject=If[ValueQ[$gitFolder],
      StringTemplate["\"`gitFolder`\""][<|"gitFolder"->$gitFolder|>],"\"wolfram-wakatime\""])


GetCurrentFile[]:=If[Not[Enclose[StringReplace[Quiet@Confirm@NotebookFileName[],"\\"->"/"],Null&]===Null],
  Set[$CurrentFile,StringReplace[Quiet@NotebookFileName[],"\\"->"/"]],
  Unset[$CurrentFile]];


ManageEvaluationNotebookChange[]:=(#;If[Not[$CurrentNotebook===EvaluationNotebook[]],
  Quiet@Unset@Once[Message[WakaTime::unsaved]];GetGitFolder[];GetCurrentProject[];GetCurrentFile[];Unset@#];#;)&@
  Unevaluated[Once[$CurrentNotebook=Quiet@EvaluationNotebook[]]];


SendHeartbeat[]:=If[ValueQ[$CurrentFile],StartProcess[{$wakaEXE, "--write",
  "--plugin"  ,
StringTemplate["\"Mathematica-wakatime-gravifer-plugin/`PlugInVersion`\""][<|"PlugInVersion"->$WakaTimePluginVersion|>],
  "--entity"  ,
StringTemplate["\"`CurrentFile`\""][<|"CurrentFile"->$CurrentFile|>],
  "--language",
"\"Wolfram\"",
  "--project", 
StringTemplate["\"`CurrentProject`\""][<|"CurrentProject"->$CurrentProject|>]}],
      Once[Message[WakaTime::unsaved]]]


$PreRead=(ManageEvaluationNotebookChange[];If[UpdateHeartbeat[],SendHeartbeat[]];
If[ValueQ[$WakaTimePreReadBackUp],$WakaTimePreReadBackUp[#],#])&;


End[]


EndPackage[]
```

Downloading the file from [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gravifer/48dad1b2192741ac718f739eb1a25a30) and follow the guide there should help you try this out. Everything is still in the early stage.